# Angular 2 Injecting ActivatedRoute returns root route

Tags: angular, router

I have the following routes that I import to app module:

```
// app.routing.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'home', loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module#HomeModule'
      }
    ] 
  }
]

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);

// app.module.ts
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {CoreModule} from './core/core.module';
import {routing} from './app.routing';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Then, in the `Home` module I have:

```
// home.routing.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: {
      pageTitle: 'Home'
    }
  }
];
export const homeRoutes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);

// home.module.ts
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {HomeComponent} from './home.component';
import {homeRoutes} from './home.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    homeRoutes
  ],
  declarations: [HomeComponent]
})
export class HomeModule {
}
```

I want to get `data` for the route, I have component `HeaderComponent` which is located in the `Layout` module. This module doesn't contains any routes, just layout components. and I want to get `data` there:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
            private router: Router) {
   }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.activatedRoute.data
        .subscribe(d => {
         console.log(d);           
      });       
   }
}
```

But, object is empty all the time. I noticed that `activatedRoute` is different, it's for `MainLayoutComponent`:

[image]

In order to get exactly my route for the `/home` I have to go to the children twice and there will be `activatedRoute` that I need and there is my `pageTitle` in the `data`.

The question is, how to get the correct `activatedRoute`? I dont want to have loop that go to the children until they will finished.
PS. This is template for `MainLayoutComponent`:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try using `snapshot` of Activated Route [Link](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#snapshot)

Comment: @RahulSingh yes, `snapshot` is also has `MainLayoutComponent` as `component`  and `data` is empty.

Comment: can you try converting it to string using `toString()` of Activated Route and see what the route value is ?

Comment: @RahulSingh the output is `Route(url:'', path:'')`

Comment: strange i guess something to do with lazy loading might be let me c

Comment: the expected path should be `' '` shouldn't it as you are redirecting to home ?

Comment: @RahulSingh sorry, don't understand your last message

Comment: which path do you navigate to? show full code how you register routes

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi sorry for the delay, but all routes that I have described in the question.

Comment: @user348173, you didn't show how you register them

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi I updated the question.

Comment: If you are injecting the `ActivatedRoute` on `AppComponent`, this is expected behavior. If it's not `AppComponent`, which component is it where you inject the `ActivatedRoute`?

Comment: @user348173, okay, and now in what component do you write `constructor(private activatedRoute:`?

Comment: It's a header component. I added some code to the question.